# Maximum / minimum value of type in F#

Tags: .net, f#, max, minimum, unchecked

`Unchecked.defaultof<'T>` generates the default value for any type. Is there such a generic function to generate the maximum / minimum value for any type where the type having a maximum / minimum value makes sense?

**EDIT**

To answer John Palmer's question of where I think it would be useful: I want to create a "mutable" version of the below function:

```
let InternalArrDiffMax (s : 'T []) (diff : 'T -> 'T -> 'C) =
    s
    |> Array.mapi (fun i e -> 
        [| for j in i + 1 .. s.Length - 1 -> diff e s.[j] |]
        |> Array.maxBy (fun n -> n))
    |> Array.maxBy (fun e -> e)
```

Since I can't declare a mutable variable without assigning value to it, I don't think there is other way to do it than:

```
let InternalArrDiffMax (s : 'T []) (diffFun : 'T -> 'T -> 'C) =
    let mutable max : 'C = // Generic max of 'C if it makes sense

    for i in 0 .. s.Length - 1 do
        for j in i + 1 .. s.Length - 1 do
            let diff = diffFun s.[i] s.[j]
            if (i = 0 && j = 1) || max < diff then
                max <- diff

    max
```

Which is why I think I need a generic max.

Comment: I don't think so (well never seen anything like it - maybe there is one) - IMO it would not make much sense **because** there is **no** maximum for *all* types.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? getting the maximum in a generic way is probably not particularly useful

Comment: See https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl , implement `Bounded` as defined in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded , then send a pull request.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Good suggestion. I just [added](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/commit/cf6e749dd4f15eed2d04927e4abd8ea6e8a32d69) it to FsControl .

Comment: @Gustavo: could you do an example usage for Bounded in FsControl.Core?

Comment: Sure @sgtz here is it https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/commit/42f10bed6ddc80df9330983eacbe59af918ad2ad

Comment: @Gustavo: wow.  Really elegant.  ty.  Is "type MaxValue = MaxValue with" documented somewhere?  I gather that it's a kind of union, but couldn't find the notation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx) or [here](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-extensions/).

Comment: @sgtz Exactly, that's a type that in fact represents a method, that's why I call it a Type Method, basically it's a Type or Single Case DU that contains overloaded methods. This technique is partially documented in the project's readme.md file, but you can find more information in my old posts at http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net. The sample files are also helpful. I don't think you will find anything about this technique in Microsoft's sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must proceed on this route, there's always Reflection. However, I would advise against use of `MaxValue` as an out-of-band or special value.

```
let inline tryGetMaxValue< ^a> () =
    match typeof< ^a>.GetField("MaxValue") with
    | null -> None
    | fieldInfo -> fieldInfo.GetValue() |> unbox< ^a> |> Some

let maxvi = tryGetMaxValue<int>()            // val maxvi : int option = Some 2147483647
let maxvf : float option = tryGetMaxValue()  // val maxvf : float option = Some 1.797693135e+308
let maxvs : string option = tryGetMaxValue() // val maxvs : string option = None
```

Answer (score 7):

@kaefer's answer gives you a good way to get the max/min values where applicable, but for your particular use case I suggest you make your mutable variable `'C option` instead, and initialize it to `None`. No magic numbers required that way.

```
let InternalArrDiffMax (s : 'T []) (diffFun : 'T -> 'T -> 'C) =
    let mutable max : 'C option = None

    for i in 0 .. s.Length - 1 do
        for j in i + 1 .. s.Length - 1 do
            let diff = diffFun s.[i] s.[j]
            match max with
            | None -> 
                max <- Some diff
            | Some v when v < diff -> 
                max <- Some diff
            | _ -> ()

    max
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution to my underlying problem but I had to mark @kaefer's reply as the answer. I'd like to vote you up but I don't even have enough reputations to do so... Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @bugfoot: Sure, I don't mind. He answered the question. You can always come back for an upvote ;)

Answer (score 2):

An approach without reflection

```
let maxOfT (x:'t) : 't = 
  match typedefof<'t> with
  | u when u=typedefof<Int16> -> Int16.MaxValue :> obj
  | u when u=typedefof<Int32> -> Int32.MaxValue :> obj
  // ... repeat for each type
  | _ -> failwith "unrecognised"
  :?> 't
let minOfT (x:'t) : 't = 
  match typedefof<'t> with
  | u when u=typedefof<Int16> -> Int16.MinValue :> obj
  | u when u=typedefof<Int32> -> Int32.MinValue :> obj
  // ... repeat for each type
  | _ -> failwith "unrecognised"
  :?> 't
```

Comment: This is partial and breaks parametricity. Do not recommend.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: the MaxValue / MinValue in .Net is a static convention.  Please advise which solutions do not break parametricity.

Comment: See Gustavo's comment and link above.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: thanks for the heads up.  A helpful addition.  I agree with the need for "bounded" but I'd also like a functional way to retrieve minValue or maxValue.  I'll ping Gustavo.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: actually, after thinking about it, for most cases I prefer your suggestion + Gustavo's implementation.  Thanks for erring towards putting the load on the compiler by putting type safety first.  That's what you were getting at with parametricity right?

Comment: see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7810909/media/doc/parametricity.pdf for a nice introduction to parametricity.